# Erlang database server nodedown error, can not get mnesia database data through database logic

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, mnesia

I am implementing an ***Erlang/OTP*** **basic chat application** with a chat server and database logic(for Mnesia). I want a database server as the middle person. This **chat server** and **database** both are **distributed**. So, I can spawn new chat users(by using chat server) with their node name. I can initialize the database for each available user nodes and so, db table will be replicated to every node. **I can access data through database logic code**. But can not do any database operations with database server.
I started db server,output:

```
(john@DESKTOP-RD414DV)7> database_server:start_link([node()|nodes()]).
{local,database_server} (<0.129.0>) starting...
```

**This is database logic code**

```
-export([install/1, get_db/1, get_all_dbe/1, delete_db/1, store_db/4]).
-include_lib("stdlib/include/qlc.hrl").
-record(userDetails, {node,username, location, gender}).
%%initialize database
install(Nodes) ->
  ok = mnesia:create_schema(Nodes),
  rpc:multicall(Nodes, application, start, [mnesia]),
  try
      mnesia:table_info(type,userDetails)
  catch
      exit:_  ->
        mnesia:create_table(userDetails, [{attributes, record_info(fields, userDetails)},
          {type, bag},
          {disc_copies, Nodes}])
  end.


store_db(Node, Username, Location, Gender) ->
  F = fun() ->
    mnesia:write(#userDetails{node =Node, username = Username, location = Location, gender = Gender})
      end,
  mnesia:transaction(F).

get_db(Node) ->
  F = fun() ->
    Query = qlc:q([X || X <- mnesia:table(userDetails),
      X#userDetails.node =:= Node]),
    Results = qlc:e(Query),
    lists:map(fun(Item) -> Item#userDetails.username end, Results)
      end,
  mnesia:transaction(F).

get_all_dbe(Node) ->
  F = fun() ->
    Query = qlc:q([X || X <- mnesia:table(userDetails),
      X#userDetails.node =:= Node]),
    Results = qlc:e(Query),
    lists:map(fun(Item) -> {Item#userDetails.username, Item#userDetails.location, Item#userDetails.gender} end, Results)
      end,
  mnesia:transaction(F).

delete_db(Node) ->
  F = fun() ->
    Query = qlc:q([X || X <- mnesia:table(userDetails),
      X#userDetails.node =:= Node]),
    Results = qlc:e(Query),

    FF = fun() ->
      lists:foreach(fun(Result) -> mnesia:delete_object(Result) end, Results)
         end,
    mnesia:transaction(FF)
      end,
  mnesia:transaction(F).
```

**This is database server code:**

```
-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start_link/1, store/4, getalldb/1, delete/1]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2,
  code_change/3]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

-record(database_server_state, {}).
%%%===================================================================
%%% Spawning and gen_server implementation
%%%===================================================================

start_link(Nodes) ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, Nodes, []).


init(Nodes) ->
  process_flag(trap_exit, true),
  io:format("~p (~p) starting...~n", [{local, ?MODULE}, self()]),
  database_logic:install(Nodes),
  {ok, #database_server_state{}}.

store(Node, Username, Location, Gender) ->
  gen_server:call({local, ?MODULE}, {store_db, Node, Username, Location, Gender}).
%%getdb(Node) ->
%%  gen_server:call({local, ?MODULE}, {get_db, Node}).

getalldb(Node) ->
  gen_server:call({local, ?MODULE}, {get_all_db, Node}).
delete(Node) ->
  gen_server:call({local, ?MODULE}, {delete, Node}).

handle_call({store_db, Node, Username, Location, Gender}, _From, State = #database_server_state{}) ->
  database_logic:store_db(Node, Username, Location, Gender),
  io:format("userdetails are saved!"),
  {reply, ok, State};

%%handle_call({get_db, Node}, _From, State = #database_server_state{}) ->
%%  X = database_logic:get_db(Node),
%%  {_, [Name]} = X,
%%  io:format("SENDER NAME: ~p~n", [Name]),
%%  {reply, ok, State};

handle_call({get_all_db, Node}, _From, State = #database_server_state{}) ->
  Y = database_logic:get_all_dbe(Node),
  {_, [{Name, Location, Gender}]} = Y,
  io:format("SENDER NAME: ~p\t LOCATION: ~p\t GENDER: ~p~n", [Name,Location,Gender]),
  {reply, ok, State};

handle_call({delete, Node},  _From, State = #database_server_state{}) ->
  database_logic:delete_db(Node),
  io:format("~p node data deleted!", [Node]),
  {reply, ok, State}.

handle_cast(_Request, State = #database_server_state{}) ->
  {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State = #database_server_state{}) ->
  {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State = #database_server_state{}) ->
  ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State = #database_server_state{}, _Extra) ->
  {ok, State}.
```

This error is found when i do store, getdb etc, database operations.(it says that NODEDOWN, but all nodes are running)

```
(john@DESKTOP-RD414DV)9> database_server: getalldb("mary@DESKTOP-RD414DV").
** exception exit: {{nodedown,database_server},
                    {gen_server,call,
                                [{local,database_server},
                                 {get_all_db,"mary@DESKTOP-RD414DV"}]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 367)
```

Comment: Seems you have not started db server process. _Sidenote:_ please post error messages as plain text, images for that are not welcome here.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I have started the server process and I got the output as 1st code segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `gen_server:call` calls:

```
gen_server:call({local, ?MODULE}, {get_all_db, Node}).
```

The way you specify the name of the server process is different between `start_link` and `call`. In `start_link`, you specify `{local, myname}` in order to register the name `myname` on the local node, but in `call` you would just specify `myname`.

If you pass a tuple with two elements to `gen_server:call`, it treats the first element as a process name, and the second element as a node name. So in the code above, it tries to make a remote call to the process registered as `local` on the node `database_server` - and this fails, because there is no node called `database_server` (not least because a node name without an `@` sign is invalid). That's why `nodedown` is the error we get.

So change the lines with `gen_server:call` to something like:

```
gen_server:call(?MODULE, {get_all_db, Node}).
```

---

You can see the difference between the two conventions in the `gen_server` documentation. Compare [the `server_name()` type spec](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#type-server_name) used in `start_link` and [the `server_ref()` type spec](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#type-server_ref) used in `call`.

Comment: should I change io:format("~p (~p) starting...~n", [{local, ?MODULE}, self()]), and this also  gen_server:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, Nodes, [ ])..by removing only the local in calls give me error.

Comment: (mary@DESKTOP-RD414DV)4> database_server: store("mary@DESKTOP-RD414DV", "Mary","Chilaw","Male").
** exception exit: {noproc,
                       {gen_server,call,
                           [database_server,
                            {store_db,"mary@DESKTOP-RD414DV","Mary","Chilaw",
                                "Male"}]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 367)

Comment: I get this above error when i execute store operation on another node, when I run this on same node (node I've run start_link) it runs successfully. I think I should change something here to globally set up the db server affecting all nodes I think. may I?

Comment: The `noproc` error there means that there is no process registered as `database_server` on the local node. To make a remote call, use `gen_server:call({database_server, 'john@DESKTOP-RD414DV'}, ...)`.

Comment: Still other nodes can not find the db server. it takes infinity timeout on other nodes when I call for data.

Comment: When I call this on any node directly it works and return data successfully.  gen_server:call({database_server,'john@DESKTOP-RD414DV'}, {get_all_db, "name of db record i need"}). but not work when running whole program. Should I globally re register thi database_server process??

Comment: I changed io:format() in to a variable list of data (Z) and returned {ok,Z}. gen_server:call({database_server, 'john@DESKTOP-RD414DV'}, ...) worked. The next noproc error was because there were no node data stored in db for the searched one. It worked. Thank you. @Legoscia

Comment: can you help me in this question please 
@legoscia https://stackoverflow.com/q/73726447/15838526