# how can I use Erlang/OTP gen_statem for a distributed chat server

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I am developing a chat server and it is distributed. I can spawn new users (using start_link) in multiple nodes and can send a message to a node, then received message will be shown on received node. I have no idea how should I use gen_statem(FSM) for this application. I need to add a FSM between two chat users(nodes). I have used a record to save states of sender, receiver and message also. Could someone suggest me how to add gen_statem here ?
I need to visualize the states received, sent respectively for send_message and receive message events.

**chat server:**

```
-module(message_server).

-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([send_message/2, receive_message/3, start_link/1, stop/0, receive_db_data/1]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2,
  code_change/3]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

-record(message_server_state, {from, to, msgsent, msgreceived}).
%%%===================================================================
%%% Spawning and gen_server implementation
%%%===================================================================

start_link(Name) ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Name, []).

init(Name) ->
  io:format("~p is connected with the server...~n", [Name]),
  {ok, #message_server_state{
    from = node(),
    to = [],
    msgsent = [],
    msgreceived = []
  }}.
stop() ->
  gen_server:stop(?MODULE).

receive_db_data(Sender) ->
  database_server:getalldb(Sender).

send_message(To, Msg) ->
  gen_server:call({?MODULE, node()}, {send, To, Msg}).

receive_message(Sender, To, Msg) ->
  gen_server:call({?MODULE, list_to_atom(To)}, {reciv, Sender, Msg}).

handle_call({send, To, Msg}, _From, State = #message_server_state{to = Receivers, msgsent = Msgsent, from = Sender}) ->
  io:format("Sent message: ~p~n", [Msg]),
  receive_message(Sender, To, Msg),
  {reply, ok, State#message_server_state{msgsent = [Msg | Msgsent], to = [To | Receivers]}};

handle_call({reciv, Sender, Msg}, _From, State = #message_server_state{msgreceived = Msgreceived}) ->
  io:format("Sent by: ~p~n", [Sender]),
  io:format("Message: ~p~n", [Msg]),
  receive_db_data(Sender),
  {reply, ok, State#message_server_state{msgreceived = [Msg | Msgreceived]}}.

handle_cast(_Request, State = #message_server_state{}) ->
  {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State = #message_server_state{}) ->
  {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State = #message_server_state{}) ->
  ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State = #message_server_state{}, _Extra) ->
  {ok, State}.
```